# Can PostgreSQL query external Microsoft Dynamics REST API directly?

Tags: django, postgresql

Our most up-to-date client information is stored in Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM and would like to query it anytime information related to it is needed to make sure the internal PostgreSQL database has the most current information.

I read through the documentation and am pretty familiar with the Web API for CRM. What I am wondering is can PostgreSQL itself, which I am fairly new to, request against an external API? That way I was thinking I could make a trigger to request the necessary data from it.

If not, I'll just do it via Django, put it into a temporary table, and `UPDATE`/`INSERT` into the `auth_user` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL has [Foreign Data Wrappers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html), which let you use external data sources as tables within a database. If there's one to suit you, then you're good to go. You'll find [a list of available FDWs on the PostreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers).